# Can i have a gitlab pipeline based on another use common job steps

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have 2 fairly similar pipelines with different objectives, so that there is a lot of jobs and stages that seem familiar, but some that are not, and some variables that are the same functionally but must different values in both.

Can I build a common pipeline, that is used by both pipelines, to cut down the duplicate code and separate out the different unique aspects of the 2 pipelines, making maintenance and testing easier?

Have been looking at include, extends, and !reference keywords but tbh I am a newbie in gitlab pipelines, and a nudge in the right direction would help.

I tried looking at include, extends and !reference

Answer (score 1):

One option you have here is to create a `common.yaml` file in one of your repos (lets call it `common.yml` and your repo `my_repo`).
you can define your jobs in this yaml file like the example below:

```
# content  of common.yml

my_job:
   do stuff#
```

And you can include this job into your same repo's cicd like this:

```
include:
  - local: 'common.yml'

my_job:
   stage: my_stage
   ...
```

Also you can include this job in **other repos** like this:

```
include:
  project: my_repo
  file: common.yml

my_job:
  stage: my_stage
  ...
```

This way when you change `my_job` in your `common.yml` file, the changes will appear in the same repo as well as on all repos that include `my_job`